# Unable to Send Data in header to Spring Boot application in Angular 6

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, angular5

I am trying to hit my Spring Boot APIs using Angular 6. I am sending some data as a part of headers like this

```
const headers  = new HttpHeaders({
    'X-TenantID': tenantId,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
});
this.httpClient.get(this.constants.urls.TENANT.VALIDATE + '/' + tenantId, {headers: headers });
```

At the back end, I am using interceptor and there i am trying to get 'X-TenantID' from my request Headers like this

```
if (request.getHeader("X-TenantID") != null) {
        String tenantName = request.getHeader("X-TenantID");
        ThreadLocaleStorage.setTenant(tenantName);
        return tenantName;
    }
```

And unfortunately its always returning null value for 'X-TenantID'. When I tried to print all headers it giving me following response

```
host
localhost:8080
connection
keep-alive
access-control-request-method
GET
origin
http://localhost:4200
user-agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
dnt
1
access-control-request-headers
**x-tenantid**
accept
*/*
accept-encoding
gzip, deflate, br
accept-language
en-US,en;q=0.9
```

It's clear x-tenantid is present in headers but why I am not getting the value for it. 
Please help me, how can I get this value from headers.

Comment: Can you access other headers from the backend?

Comment: I found the problem, I think. The problem is with pre-flight request sent by the browser before sending actual request does not have the specified parameters in headers. And I am checking headers for each and every request for these headers in Interceptors. For now, I just skip the requests coming with 'OPTION' method (Pre-Flight request by browser is always 'OPTION' type), and its working because actual request has the specified headers. It's hack, I know. I am looking for better solution.

Comment: How do you send the request in Angular?